# Install f-spot - no installation candidate

Tags: apt, aptitude

I tried to install f-spot, but apt says there is no installation candidate for f-spot:

```
$ sudo apt-get install f-spot
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

Package f-spot is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'f-spot' has no installation candidate
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot install f-spot this way any more, because it has been dropped from recent software distributions (as of 2014 or 2012). Cf. http://packages.ubuntu.com/f-spot and https://packages.debian.org/f-spot

"The most recent version of F-Spot is 0.8.2, released December 19, 2010." – on [f-spot.org](http://f-spot.org)